# About Timezone And Post Ranking

Tags: timezones

I am using Wordpress CMS. I had started my blog 2 years back. Right now I have “284” blog post in my sitemap. When I started my blog that time. I did mistake while selecting time zone for my blog. I live in India my time zone should be UTC+05:30 or kolkata, but I have selected there UTC-5:30 by mistake. Now I am getting wrong published time in my every blog post.

Now my question is that if i make changes in time zone & correct it to UTC+05:30 or kolkata. In wordpress>> general setting>> Time zone setup. Will it create any problem for my all blog post ranking in Google search engine? Because after making changes in time zone. It will automatically make changes in “post sitemap” timing. and it also makes changes in google search console.

Comment: You might have better luck asking SEO-related questions on the [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).